# svn checkout only latest files?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to checkout a project on my local directory. The size of that project files is not very large but the files in .svn folder is huge addition to the project size. Is there any way to just download the project files but still I can commit and update code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checkout repo, you always get .svn dir.

But if you want to get **unversioned tree** of repository, you can use `export`

`svn export URL PATH`

Comment: He asked to still be able to commit and update. You can't commit or update from an exported copy.

Comment: There is an ongoing work to make some parts of the .svn directory optional and therefore minimize its size (see [ticket #525](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-525) and https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/subversion-dev/202107.mbox/%3c874kcf6xin.fsf@red-bean.com%3e)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. If you use 1.7 it will only keep one .svn directory at the root of the working copy. It needs the .svn directory to have metadata about each file, and the pristine version of the file to allow you to do diffs revert and other things without network access.

If you don't need all the directories, you can use [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)

And as explained by Lazy Badger, you can use svn export, but you will not be able to commit or update from an exported working copy.